# Building objects in one class and accessing them in another

Tags: java, object

I'm creating a choose your own adventure "game" as part of a group project.  My idea is to make an object of type StoryRoom, that would store information such as description of that StoryRoom, what other StoryRooms connect to it, etc.  I also want to have a class to create an adventure, which will be an array of StoryRooms.  The idea is that the main program will cycle through StoryRooms, displaying the text and returning a value when a decision is made that will be the reference for the next StoryRoom, until the player reaches an end scenario.

The problem I am having is that I cannot access the StoryRooms created in my AdventureBuilder class through the AdventureTeller class.  AdventureTeller is the driver class for the game.  Eclipse throws an error that entryway cannot be resolved as a variable.  How can I fix this?

```
public class StoryRoom {
    public String[] description = null;
    public int[] exits;


    public StoryRoom(String[] builddescriptions, int[] buildexits){
        description = new String[builddescriptions.length];
        exits = new int[buildexits.length];
        for (int i = 0; i< builddescriptions.length; i++){
            description[i] = builddescriptions[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i< buildexits.length; i++){
            exits[i] = buildexits[i];
        }

    }

    public String GetDescription(int reference){
        return description[reference];
    }

    public int GetExit(int reference){
        return exits[reference];
    }

}


public class AdventureTeller {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdventureBuilder.main();
        for (int i = 0; i < entryway.description.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(entryway.GetDescription(i));
        }

    }

}




public class AdventureBuilder {

    public static void main() {
        // StoryRoom[] book = new StoryRoom[20];
        String[] description = null;
        description = new String[3];
        int[] exits;
        exits = new int[3];

        description[0] = "This is a strange room with 2 doors, one on the left and one on the right.";
        description[1] = "Take the left door? (enter 1)";
        description[2] = "Take the right door? (enter 2)";
        exits[0] = 1; // current room number
        exits[1] = 2;
        exits[2] = 3;
        StoryRoom entryway = new StoryRoom(description, exits);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the scope of the object, and that they are being destroyed as soon as AdventureBuilder's main is done running.  I tried passing the object or array of objects (the commented code) back as a return value, but was unsuccesful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing AdventureBuilder alone won't be quite enough.  You'll also need to change AdventureTeller.  New versions of both classes below (tested working against Java 1.6):

```
public class AdventureBuilder
{
    private StoryRoom entryway;

    // Avoid naming a method 'main' unless it's the main method of your main class
    // Try something like 'initAdventureBuilder()' instead
    public void main()
    {
        // StoryRoom[] book = new StoryRoom[20];
        String[] description = null;
        description = new String[3];
        int[] exits;
        exits = new int[3];

        description[0] = "This is a strange room with 2 doors, one on the left and one on the right.";
        description[1] = "Take the left door? (enter 1)";
        description[2] = "Take the right door? (enter 2)";

        exits[0] = 1; // current room number
        exits[1] = 2;
        exits[2] = 3;

        entryway = new StoryRoom(description, exits);
    }

    // A way for AdventureBuilder to be questioned about its entryway field

    public StoryRoom getStoryRoom()
    {
        return entryway;
    }
}

public class AdventureTeller
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creating a copy of AdventureBuilder that AdventureTeller knows about
        AdventureBuilder ab = new AdventureBuilder();
        StoryRoom entryway;

        // Asking AdventureBuilder to run itself 
        ab.main();

        // Asking AdventureBuilder for a reference to the entryway which it created
        // when you asked AdventureBuilder to run itself

        entryway = ab.getStoryRoom();

        for (int i = 0; i < entryway.description.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(entryway.GetDescription(i));
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to avoid using `main` as a method name for any method other than the one that starts your program.  Try to use descriptive method names like `initAdventureBuilder()` or something like that, to avoid confusion.  When I first looked at your code, I assumed AdventureBuilder was the main class because of your naming conventions, when in fact, it was not.

Just so you know what was happening, when you tried to compile, the compiler was complaining about not having any idea what the entryway field in AdventureTeller referred to.  Even if you had commented out that line of code just to get it to compile, AdventureTeller would still have no clue what fields were inside AdventureBuilder unless you explicitly told AdventureTeller what was there.  And to make things worse, you never created a copy of AdventureBuilder within AdventureTeller.

Answer (score 3):

In the code you've posted, `entryway` is not an instance variable, it's a method variable--its scope is limited to your `AdventureBuilder.main()` method. If you want it accessible outside the class and outside that method, make it an instance variable (or return it and then the calling method can use it).

Answer (score 1):

Just fixing your code according to Catherine's advice, this is what it should look like.

```
...

public class AdventureBuilder {

    StoryRoom entryway;

    public static void main() {
        // StoryRoom[] book = new StoryRoom[20];
        String[] description = null;
        description = new String[3];
        int[] exits;
        exits = new int[3];

        description[0] = "This is a strange room with 2 doors, one on the left and one on the right.";
        description[1] = "Take the left door? (enter 1)";
        description[2] = "Take the right door? (enter 2)";
        exits[0] = 1; // current room number
        exits[1] = 2;
        exits[2] = 3;
        entryway = new StoryRoom(description, exits);
    }
}
```